# Each DIV can't be 50% in this two column CSS layout?

Tags: html, css

### The Problem

The second `DIV` is wrapping if both widths are `50%`, but if I make the width of *one* of the `DIVs` `49%` it will layout as two columns. Is this the expected behavior or am I doing something wrong?

### CSS

```
.box
{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
}

.box.twocolumn .column1
{
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.box.twocolumn .column2
{
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

### HTML

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="box twocolumn">
        <div class="column1">
            <label>
                Start Date:</label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="StartDate" CssClass="datepicker" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
        <div class="column2">
            <label>
                End Date:</label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="EndDate" CssClass="datepicker" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: is this happening in any browser or just IE?

Comment: @dnagirl, Right now I'm only testing it in IE, that is my primary use browser so I generally get it working there first.

Comment: It's working fine for me on chrome, see -> https://tinker.io/c5283

Comment: I've also tested the above link on IE8 and works fine. Try to provide a testcase that reproduce the problem, probably you are adding some margin in your html that made second div to wrap.

Comment: @BigM : Which version of IE are you using?

Comment: @dnagirl actually that should cause the divs fit into one line and not vice versa becaue the proprietary MS-boxmodell is smaller then the w3c one. In the OPs case the wc3 boxmodell is more likely to break. Also with css3 you can switch to the MS box-model via `box-sizing:border-box` - this might already fix the problem.

Comment: @Christoph: I withdraw my box model comment.  It does however, appear that the issue is browser specific.

Comment: @PranavKapoor, I'm testing in IE9

Comment: @Nelson, I see what you're saying, and that works fine in the same browser I'm testing in, so it must be inherited CSS that's causing the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is very vague, but I try to give an answer which might solve your problem:

At first you should always include a proper doctype, to make all browsers behave the same way. The recommended one is `<!DOCTYPE html>`. It works in all browsers, even IE6.

Also you have to be aware of the possible [box-models](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_box_model_bug).

Now you can try out to set the `box-sizing` property on your divs like [in this example](http://jsfiddle.net/yuypE/). Also, set the display-type to `display:inline-block`, because `width` is not recognized on inline elements!

The first two divs fit on one line, because the have the `box-sizing:border-box` declaration - both the border and the padding are included into the `50%` width.

The second two divs break because they have standard w3c-box modell. The `50%` width only account for the content, padding and border are added to the width, thus exceeding `100%` total width.

I'm pretty sure this could fix your problem. If this is the case you have some css elsewhere in your code, which modifies your divs (adding border/padding) to make them wrap.

Comment: Maybe mention W3C code validation and how IE hates invalid HTML.

Comment: This lead me to my answer, as I began searching to understand the box model I found the Twitter Bootstrap (http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/index.html) which handles all of the box model problems and builds CSS that will work in all browsers. Thank you for helping me better understand my problem!